# What is `.github/CONTRIBUTING.md` for?

Tags: github

I found some repositories on GitHub that have a dot-folder `.github` and a file `CONTRIBUTING.md` in it.

Usually I knew `md`-files in the repositories root folder but not in a dot-sub-folder.

What is this file for? Is it linked somewhere in the GitHub web-frontend?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/communities/setting-up-your-project-for-healthy-contributions/setting-guidelines-for-repository-contributors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comes from 2012 "[Contributing Guidelines](https://github.blog/2012-09-17-contributing-guidelines/)"

> Oftentimes open source projects place a CONTRIBUTING file in the root directory.
>
> It explains how a participant should do things like format code, test fixes, and submit patches.
>
> Here is a fine [example](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) from [puppet](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet) and [another one](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) from [`factory_girl_rails`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails).
>
> From a maintainer’s point of view, the document succinctly communicates how best to collaborate. And for a contributor, one quick check of this file verifies their submission follows the maintainer’s guidelines.
>
> As a maintainer, all you have to do is add a `CONTRIBUTING` file (or `CONTRIBUTING.md` if you’re using Markdown) to the root of your repository.
> Then we will add a link to your file when a contributor creates an Issue or opens a Pull Request.

[image]

Since then, it is documented in "[Setting guidelines for repository contributors](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/setting-up-your-project-for-healthy-contributions/setting-guidelines-for-repository-contributors)"

It includes:

> To help your project contributors do good work, you can add a file with contribution guidelines to your project repository's root, docs, or `.github` folder.

So this is a new alternative location for that file.

> If a repository contains more than one `CONTRIBUTING` file, then the file shown in links is chosen from locations in the following order:
>
> - the `.github` directory, then
> - the repository's root directory, and finally
> - the docs directory.

From [Feb. 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-02-21-organization-wide-community-health-files/)

> Organizations can now add community health files to a specially named `.github` repository to serve as organization-wide defaults for all repositories within their organization.
>
> You can add `CONTRIBUTING`, `SUPPORT`, `CODE_OF_CONDUCT`, `ISSUE_TEMPLATE(S)`, or `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE(S)` files to a public, organization-owned `.github` repository, and if a given community health file doesn’t exist for a repository, the organization-wide default will be used.
>
> While the file itself won’t appear in the file browser or Git history for each repository, it will be surfaced throughout developers’ workflows, such as when opening a new issue or when viewing the Community Profile, just as if it were committed to the repository directly.

---

As noted by [DrBeco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670521/drbeco) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72929081/what-is-github-contributing-md-for/72929094#comment134932374_72929094), the same applies to GitLab: "**[Description templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html)**", for issues and pull requests, not directly for contribution though:

> You can define templates to use as descriptions for your issues and merge requests.
>
> You can define these templates in a project, group, or instance. Projects inherit the templates defined at a higher level.

Comment: This doc you quote talks about that file in the projects root. But I talk about that file in a `.github` sub-folder.

Comment: @buhtz Yes, I have edited the answer to address that.

Comment: @buhtz I also mention the org-level file. `CONTRIBUTING` is part of a set of "health files".

Comment: Is there a documentation help for `gitlab`?

Comment: @DrBeco Not that I know of. You have examples, like [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) or [`gitlab-org/gitlab-pages`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/-/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md), but no official documentation. The "[Good doc project](https://gitlab.com/tgdp/templates) is an interesting one.

Comment: Later that day I found it. Let me share to keep it registered for others: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html

Comment: @DrBeco Good catch. That would not include "contributing" though, I believe.

Comment: Yep. Exactly, @VonC . They have a "add CONTRIBUTING" button on the website project overview, but it is added in the root of the project, not inside `.gitlab` I replied to some issue asking them to change that, giving my upvote. Link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28005